# jquerymobile ermm browser variation in DOM change for internal linking

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to figure out exactly what happens when you link to a same-domain external page with JQM. I know the new page gets added to the DOM, but if I cruise through 5 or so of these links, are all 5 now in the DOM?

Firebug is showing the initial page and the active page in the DOM and nothing else.
Chrome is showing variable results, usually storing the last page and the active page.
What exactly happens here?

Do I need to assume all my handlers on a page are lost when I change page? So I need to rebind them on each pageinit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to check. Bind page create:

```
$('#pageID').live('pagecreate', function (event) { alert("Inserted to the dom") };
```

That triggers when the page is inserted to the dom. If the alert is triggered every time you enter the page, it means the page is not saved to the dom. And I think that is actually the case. But I am not sure.

Comment: I'm getting confused if we are supopsed to use pageinit or pagecreate

Comment: Pagecreate triggers before all the widgets have been enhanced by jQuery Mobile. Pageinit triggers after all the widgets have been enhanced by jQuery Mobile. That's the difference.